# Where to change the vmware shared folder mount point?

Tags: permissions, vmware, mountpoint

I managed to attached a shared folder with the vmware, but I need an another location to mount (not vmhgfs). I tried to create a simlink to the desired location, but it has got a root permission always (can not change). Please help. thx, István

Answer (score 0):

A symlink has always the permissions `rwxrwxrwx`, it gets its effective permission when the link is followed. You can see the effective permission and the target of the link with `ls -ldL <symlink>`.

Example:

```
root # ln -s shareddir link_to_shareddir
root # exit
$ ls -ld *shareddir*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Feb 21 19:46 link_to_shareddir -> shareddir
drwxr-xr-x 2 jean jean 4096 Feb 21 19:45 shareddir
$ ls -ldL *shareddir*
drwxr-xr-x 2 jean jean 4096 Feb 21 19:45 link_to_shareddir
drwxr-xr-x 2 jean jean 4096 Feb 21 19:45 shareddir
```

Comment: That can explain a lot. I created the soft link on a shared folder, and the permission originated from there. How can I shared folder, if such a user do not exist on the destination machine?